# Ruby thread dying when manipulating data

Tags: ruby, multithreading, callback

I am currently working with a program that utilizes callbacks in a thread to manipulate a class variable for a static class.  When any method that manipulates an object is called the thread dies.  If anyone can take a look and tell me what I am doing incorrectly, or how I could accomplish the same thing a better way, it would be very much appreciated.  Below is a simple program that replicates the issue.

In phone.rb:

```
class Phone
  @@ringer = "RingVibrateRingVibrateRing"
  def self.get_ringer
    return @@ringer
  end

  def set_ringer(new_ring)
    @@ringer = new_ring
  end

  def self.calling_you(reached)
    puts "Calling you.  "
    t = Thread.new {
      sleep(3)
      reached.call
      Thread.exit
    }
    sleep(10)
    puts "Thanks for calling me back!"
  end
end
```

In CallTree.rb

```
require 'thread'
require 'C:\Users\mabauer\Desktop\phone.rb'


def calling_you_back
  ring_sound = Phone.get_ringer
  puts "#{ring_sound}"
  # The following line is where issues occur, when commented it works fine
  Phone.set_ringer("RingingRingingRinging")
  ring_sound = Phone.get_ringer
  puts "#{ring_sound}"
  puts "I called you back."
end

begin
  Phone.calling_you(method(:calling_you_back))
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set up an exception handler in your thread so you can see if anything goes wrong:

```
begin
  sleep(3)
  reached.call
  Thread.exit
rescue => err
  warn err
end
```

Alternatively, you can make your script abort with a backtrace when any thread raises an exception:

```
Thread.abort_on_exception = true
```

The error I see is that `set_ringer` is not a class method. Make sure you define it as `self.set_ringer`.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `Phone.set_ringer(...)` but `set_ringer` is defined as an instance method. Make it a class method (`def self.set_ringer(...)`) and it will work.